# How to do an interactive git rebase in egg/Emacs?

Tags: git, emacs, emacs-egg

I enjoy using the egg git-front-end in emacs, but I can't figure out how to do an interactive rebase to squash several commits into one. I know how do do in from the command line, but I can't see what egg mark to use (+ . *) and which egg command (r R) to apply.

BTW. Is there a way to do git svn rebase and git svn dcommit from within egg as well?

Answer (score 1):

This is working like charm now. I think the only thing which has changed is the underlaying git version. I've done an emerge git (I'm a Gentoo user) and are using git version 1.6.3.3

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to figure this out for an hour... As far as I can tell the rebase functionality isn't working in egg. I'd try to contact the author about it. As for `git svn` support, it doesn't look like egg has this either. (Though `magit` does. As I understand `egg` is a fork of `magit`. It doesn't have interactive rebase, however, which would be very nice.)

Comment: Thank you for trying. I've tried to put the cursor over the staring sequence and typing C-u r, which gives the correct range in the buffer, but it does not seem to squash anything that I've marked.

Comment: That's about what I get. I mark stuff with . from the log buffer and use R to do the rebase... but it just fails with no error messages.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't actually used it, but a quick look at the source code suggests you need to use it from within the log display buffer.  (Not sure what that is though).  There's quite a lot of code in there dealing with interactive rebase, so I'd be surprised if it doesn't work.

Comment: I've been doing this from the log buffer using the mark commands (+ . *0 and running the rebase commands (r R), but I can't get it to work.